# /Windows/System32/config no such file or directory Linux windows partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, windows

I created a Windows partition from Ubuntu at */mnt/windows* to navigate to */mnt/windows/Windows/System32/config*
(following this instruction: https://github.com/spxak1/weywot/blob/main/guides/bt_dualboot.md).

I have no problem navigating to /mnt/windows/, but from there, when I cd /Windows/System32/config, it returns the "no such file or directory" error message.

```
username@computer:/mnt/windows$ cd Windows
bash: cd: Windows: No such file or directory
```

Here are the directories I got from using ls command:

```
username@computer:/mnt/windows$ ls
'$RECYCLE.BIN'       Recovery
'$WINRE_BACKUP_PARTITION.MARKER'  'System Volume Information'
```

Comment: There is no mention of `/mnt/windows` on the linked page. However, the name of the directory `/mnt/windows` indicates that, after creating the directory, you need to `mount` the Windows partition to that mount point. You seem to have skipped that step.

Comment: You mounted the wrong Windows partition.  Try the other ones.